# Is there a way to query module provider region from within the module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I have a module with a region and custom alias for the same.

```
provider "aws" {
  version = "=2.70.0"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  alias   = "use1"
}

module "aws-module1" {
  source      = "./modules/aws-resources"
  providers = {
    aws = aws.use1
  } 
}
```

Is there a way to query `${module.providers.aws}` to return `us-east-1` from within the module? I intend to create resources that need the region parameter when running CLI commands, like

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name aws-lambda-function --region ${module.providers.aws} ${path.module}/response.json # should ${module.providers.aws} return us-east-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after, but generally you can get the region in the module from parent using [aws_region](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/region):

> As well as validating a given region name this resource can be used to discover the name of the **region configured within the provider**. The latter can be useful in a **child module** which is inheriting an AWS provider configuration from its parent module.

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}
```